# Custom setting to show checkboxes

Tags: visualforce, customsetting

2 Objects :- Account And Products with 1:m relationship

**Account Fields**:- Account Name,Account Country (Picklist)

**Product Fields**:- Product Name(Multiselect Picklist), Product Description

---

**Account Country values**:- India, Pakistan, China, Australia

**Product Name values**:- Product 1, Product 2, Product 3, Product 4, Product 5, Product 6

---

**Dependency**:-

- India

  --- Product 1, Product 2
- Pakistan

  --- Product 1, Product 3, Product 5
- China

--- Product 1, Product 6

- Australia

  --- Product 4, Product 5, Product 6

  ---

On vf page
2 Fields
Account Country as dropdown and
All Products displayed as checkbox.

Checkboxes would be rendered based on the country selected.(Display only those products for the country selected)

Created a custom setting to store Country and Products.

Want to retrieve values accordingly.

Comment: So ... what is your question ?  While you're giving a lot of background details, it's unclear to me where your issue is and what type of answer you're expecting.

Comment: I want to achieve this using apex code.. and i am stuck up on how i traverse through custom setting values

Comment: You add an actionsupport on the select that calls a pagereference method in the controller. In this method you select the products you want to display for that country.

Comment: I assume you are not able to access the values from a custom setting. If so, please use this link to know about fetching values from a custom setting. https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=cs_accessing.htm&language=en

Comment: Thanks vijay.. this link helped me out and i am able to write the code